# Using (under score) "_" in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2

Tags: c++, netbeans

In header files i have a function

```
typedef std::vector<double> 1DVector
typedef std::vector<1DVector> 2Dvector
static void FuncA(2DVector& M, 2DVector& S, 2DVector& MSI);
```

in .cpp file

```
void ClassTemp::FuncA(2DVector& _M, 2DVector& _S, 2DVector& _MSI);
```

I am using netbeans IDE 8.0.2. When i am compiling this code, I am getting errors like

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant

error: prototype for void void ClassTemp::FuncA(2DVector& _M, 2DVecto
r& _S, 2DVector& _MSI) does not match any in class ClassTemp.

error: candidate is void ClassTemp::FuncA(2DVector& _M, 2DVector& _S, 2DVector& _MSI)
```

I searched on net and found that this is related with `_`, but previously I successfully compiled this code with netbeans IDE 7.4. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am compiling with `arm-linux-androideabi-g++` compiler.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter (for example, `_M`) are reserved for the language implementation. They could be `#define`d macros or names used for internal language implementation classes and functions. Therefore, you're not supposed to use them in your own code, since otherwise you might run into bizarre issues. I suspect that that's the issue here.

Try renaming your variable to either use a lower-case `m` or by dropping the underscore. (As a heads-up, the same rule applies to names starting with two underscores, so don't try adding another underscore on the front. ^_^)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah right, One more concern, then why it was compiled with IDE 7.4? Things changed from 7.4 to 8.0.2?

Comment: @SaadSaadi It's implementation-defined, I believe, what names with this pattern do, so it's quite possible that it would work on one compiler and not on another. Basically, you did something that wasn't guaranteed to work, so in one case it coincidentally happened to work and in the other it coincidentally didn't.

Comment: I think it is not Netbeans version dependent. It depends on the compiler also. For the 7.4 version i compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabigf` compiler.